# Query Notification setup

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am relatively new at playing around with this and have been trying to follow a tutorial on setting up in the section named "Prerequisites to Create SQL Notification Requests" within this site http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach However I am not sure what I should be putting in :://the service and there were no instructions or information on the site regarding this.  I was wondering what I should do or what other information I need to complete this section.

Answer (score 1):

The service specification is the name of the service used for query notifications.  The tutorial is focused on SqlDependency, which creates dynamically-named services (GUID appended).  No need to explicitly grant `SEND` permissions on the service in that case because the creator of the service will have `CONTROL` permissions on the service anyway.

If you were to use the lower-level SqlNotificationRequest object, then you would need to grant `SEND` on the service, `REFERENCES` on the contracts, and `RECEIVE` on the queues.  That allows a less privileged account to subscribe to query notifications.